# System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: c#, desktop

Отладка ругается на эту строку, в чем дело?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
                for (int k = 0; k < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++k)
                {
                    excelTable.Add(dataGridView1[0, k].Value.ToString());
                }
```

Ошибка: `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

Comment: `Count - 1`. Последняя строка явно пустая, значения в ней null. В общем случае поведение грида зависит от того, есть ли привязка данных или нет.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov благодарю, исправил, работает!)